# Fscanf not reading the entire popen

Tags: c, file, pointers, popen

I would like to ask if anyone know why when i put the code like this:

```
            char buff[100];
            FILE *pf = popen("/bin/file ola.png", "w");
            fscanf(pf, "%s", buff);
            pclose(pf);
```

It prints: ola.png: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract

And if i put:

```
            char buff[100];
            FILE *pf = popen("/bin/file ola.png", "r");
            fscanf(pf, "%s", buff);
            pclose(pf);
            printf("%s", buff);
```

it prints just: ola.png:

I would like it to save the entire phrase on the buffer, not just ola.png:

Thank you!

Comment: OT: Always check if `popen` fails.

Comment: `fscanf` only reads till the first whitespace. Either use `fgets` in a loop, or `fread` to read everything at once.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That fixed the problem, thank you!

Comment: "It prints: ola.png: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract" --> output may have been on `stderr`.

Answer (score 2):

> save the entire phrase on the buffer

The `"%s"` in `char buff[100]; ... fscanf(pf, "%s", buff);` directs code<sup>1</sup> to:

1. Read and skip any leading white-spaces.
2. Read and save 1 or more non-white-spaces into `buff` - possibly overrunning `buff`.
3. Continue until reading a white-space (like `'\n'`), put it back into `pf` and then append a `'\0'` to `buff`.

This does not read an entire *line* of input.  More like one "word".   It is also worse than [gets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359) lacking a *width* limit like `"%99s"`.

Instead use `fgets()` to read a *line* into a *string*.  Result includes any `'\n'`.

```
if (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, pf)) Success();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> some details omitted for brevity.  [C17dr spec details](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf).